# How to forward proxy credentials

Tags: network, proxy

My development group works at a remote office which requires us to VPN into the corporate network to get access to any company resources. The corporate network is designed to forward NTLM credentials to all websites.

This causes massive headaches for us, because we all have MacBooks and therefore do not have NTLM credentials stored, so whenever the above happens (and fails), we have to type in our ID/PW again. This happens literally 20+ times a day, and if we disconnect from the VPN and reconnect, we have to do it 20+ times yet again. No exaggeration, I have had to type my ID/PW into a browser window >50x in a single day on multiple occasions, and everyone on my 12-person team has had days that were just as bad. Clearly, this is not a positive experience. Corporate IT officially does not support OSX, so they are no help whatsoever.

What can we do to improve our experience? Like, isn't there a way to run a local proxy that will always forward NTLM credentials to any internal corporate website that asks for them? Or is there a way we can make our browsers smarter with what sites get routed through the proxy?